# Handling escaped field separators with MySQL's LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, escaping, load-data-infile

I am using `LOAD DATA INFILE` to import into a MySQL table twenty |-delimited .dat files. But some of the | field terminators are escaped with a backslash. The second field below is an example:

```
1001604|EMERITUS CORP\WA\|SC 13G|1996-02-13|edgar/data/1001604/0000728757-96-000006.txt
1001604|EMERITUS CORP\WA\|SC 13G|1996-02-14|edgar/data/1001604/0000903949-96-000038.txt
```

I get an error because the last field clashes with the `DATE` type declared for the next to last field. I can open the .dat file and escape the escape, but is there a better way?

I could use a stream editor to double all backslashes, but this seems like a bad idea. Can I safely change the `FIELDS ESCAPED BY` option to something other than "\", or is that a bad idea? Thanks!

Here is my `LOAD DATA INFILE` command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/users/richard/research/data/edgar/masterfiles/master_1996.dat'
    INTO TABLE edgar.master
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
    IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding `ESCAPED BY ''` to my `FIELDS` clause allows the query to complete without error. I will update if I find that this caused a silent fail.

Comment: `ESCAPED BY ''` is a nice solution, but it effectively disables escaping, thereby interfering with MySQL's built-in special characters, such as `\N` which is used for inserting NULL.  Another way would be to double-escape the text you're LOADing, e.g. `EMERITUS CORP\\WA\\...`